# Stripe webhook confusion

Tags: stripe-payments

I am having a hard time finding the right webhooks in Stripe to use since it seems a lot of get fired off for multiple situations.

So my site sells a few items (like 10) that can be bought as a single purchase or a subscription (you get the item every X days, no SASS jut products). I am using Stripe's Checkout and Portal to handle all subscriptions and single purchase and those parts work great. Person adds stuff to cart, checkouts out, pays, we are all good. The issue is adding an order to our system from the webhook.

Look at this scenario: a person adds 2 single items and 1 subscription to their cart. They checkout and pay. When that happens we had the `checkout.session.completed` catching the checkout session was completed and we add those items from their cart to an order. The subscription re-ups after "X" Days we would listen for the `invoice.payment_succeeded` webhook to create a new order in our system. This logic is flawed though since `invoice.payment_succeeded` is called on the first order too so basically when they checkout our system adds 2 subscription orders: one from the checkout.session.completed and one from the `invoice.payment_succeeded`. How can we handle this?

What I would like to have is:

1 webhook to know when the checkout is complete and is only called then, which they do: `checkout.session.completed`

1 webhook that is only called when a subscription is renewed, not also when created, which I cant find.

If they dont have that webhook for subscription renewals only, how can I tell in the "invoice" object is the very first one so I dont do anything on checkout, only create a new order on renewal?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `invoice.payment_succeeded` you should consider using [`invoice.paid`, as it will also fire when you mark an Invoice as paid out-of-band](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid) (which won't happen with `invoice.payment_succeeded`).  Both describe an Invoice, so you should be able to switch between them with minimal or no changes to your code.

You're correct that there is no Event specific to renewals for a Subscription only, but you can use [the `billing_reason` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason) on an Invoice to determine why the Invoice was created.  If it's the first Invoice for a new subscription the Invoice will have `billing_reason` set to `subscription_create`.